# Listing only directories in UNIX

Tags: unix, shell

I want to list only the directories in specified path (`ls` doesn't have such option).
Also, can this be done with a single line command?

Comment: For the future: Maybe unix/linux basics type of questions not so hard related to programming are better keept there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 352):

Try this `ls -d */` to list directories within the current directory

Comment: Hey, that's pretty nifty, I always used to us `ls -al | grep '^d'` - this is much more succinct.

Comment: This however gives e.g. `ls: */: No such file or directory` on `stderr` if there is no directory in the working directory. (Removed nonsense about `-d` before the other comments were posted).

Comment: No, the `-d` is not redundant. Without this parameter, `ls */` will show the contents of all directories in the current working directory.

Comment: That it does, I'm not sure if there is an easy way to overcome that. The -d is to prevent the directory contents being displayed.

Comment: why use */ ?? please explain!?

Comment: I don't have a proper explanation, however I do know that the `*/` forces the display of only items ending with a forward slash, which in this case would be a directory, even if the `-F` option of `ls` isn't used. Similar to the behaviour of `ls *php` and how it displays all files ending with `php` in a directory.

Comment: @user975234 Someone asked a similar question, and there's a pretty good explanation posted [link](http://superuser.com/questions/344877/ls-d-is-not-displaying-directories-is-there-a-way-to-get-ls-to-only-display-di)

Comment: Just `echo */` will do the same too

Comment: Note that this solution depends on wildcard expansion, thus it might fail if there is a huge amount of subdirectories, giving a message "The parameter list is too long." I prefer @Robin's solution for "single responsibility".

Comment: this won't list directories starting with `.`

Comment: I still feel that `ls -d .` should be the "list all directories in the current directory" command. Thank you for this one, though!

Comment: how do you then have the directories show in list format (so I can see the permissions) rather than pancaked all one-dimensionally?

Comment: @JeromeWileySegovia ls -ld */

Comment: If you use `ls -d {.*,*}/` it'll also list your hidden dotted folders.  If that's what you want.

Comment: @Chandeep For anyone wondering why */, this answer should clarify it: https://superuser.com/a/369960/1097408. In other words, `ls */` prints all directories with their content. Adding -d skips the latter.

Comment: @Chandeep - just to add to @SantaXL comment. `*` is just a regular expression syntax that matches 'anything'. So `ls -d */` will list literally 'anything' (except hidden files and directories) in the current directory. When followed by a forward slash `/` will list directories.

Comment: isn't that same as `echo */`?

Answer (score 105):

Try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Comment: To me this looks to be the way it should be done. Unlike the suggested `ls` solutions, `find` is solely responsible for doing the job (not relying on shell wildcard expansion, which can impose limits). It also is a lot more concise.

Comment: The bad thing about this is that it doesn't work if you are trying to loop through the results and your results have spaces in the names.

Comment: Alternatively, if you didn't want to include the directory itself: `find * -maxdepth 0 -type d`.

Comment: @ubiquibacon Either use `find`'s `-print0` or `-exec` option.

Comment: This is really slow, at least on my Mac. It seems to do the full recursive search that `find` usually does but only output the folders at depth 1.

Comment: @MattBrennan - did you test this?  `-depth 1` is definitely impractically slow, but `-maxdepth 1` is pretty quick. That said `ls -d {.*,*}/` is faster though.

Comment: Note that this produces different results from the top `ls`-based solution, in the case of hidden files. This will include hidden files (although you can [explicitly exclude them](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/320320)), whereas `ls -d */` does _not_ include hidden files.

Answer (score 28):

The following

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

basically filters the expansion of '*', i.e. all entries in the current dir, by the `-type d` condition.

Advantage is that, output is same as `ls -1 *`, but only with directories 
and entries do not start with a dot

Answer (score 13):

You can use `ls -d */` or `tree -d`

Another solution would be globbing but this depends on the shell you are using and if globbing for directories is supported.

For example ZSH:

```
zsh # ls *(/)
```

Comment: With which flavour of Unix do you get `tree`?

Comment: all major linux distries for example? sorry, I don't get the question?

Comment: I have a Debian distro, and `tree` is not installed by default (though it is in the repositories).

Comment: Downvotes as I believe the `tree` command is not a native unix command (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 11):

```
ls -l | grep '^d'
```

You can make an alias and put it into the profile file

```
alias ld="ls -l| grep '^d'"
```

Comment: links are not viewed with this command. And a link can be a file or a directory.
Example : lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    21 avril 15 17:38 cron -> /lib/init/upstart-job.

Answer (score 11):

Since there are dozens of ways to do it, here is another one:

```
tree -d -L 1 -i --noreport
```

- -d: directories
- -L: depth of the tree (hence 1, our working directory)
- -i: no indentation, print names only
- --noreport: do not report information at the end of the tree listing

Comment: And thank you for explaining the switches.  Stack Overflow is about answers, I always appreciate when people do just like you with an explanation vs. "just read the man entry!" <-- that's not an answer.

Comment: To start from line 2 (skip the line with only a dot): `tree -d -L 1 -i --noreport | tail -n +2`

Comment: This is the highest-ranked solution that lists soft-linked directories and does so in a useful manner, exposing them as a link. I prefer the variation: `tree -C -d -L 1 -i --noreport | tail -n+2`

Answer (score 7):

The answer will depend on your *shell*.

In `zsh`, for example, you can do the following:

```
echo *(/)
```

And all directories within the current working directory will be displayed.

See [`man zshexpn`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshexpn/) for more information.

An alternative approach would be to use `find(1)`, which should work on most Unix flavours:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print
```

[`find(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/find/) has many uses, so I'd definitely recommend `man find`.

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name [^\.]\* | sed 's:^\./::'
```

Comment: ☀  find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name [^\.]\* | sed 's:^\./::'
zsh: no matches found: [^.]*

Answer (score 7):

use this to get a list of directory

```
ls -d */ | sed -e "s/\///g"
```

Comment: ls -d <custom-directory-path> | sed -e "s/\///g" is not working ..any clues?

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted the directory list without all the permissions and this did the trick. :)

Answer (score 6):

In order to list the directories in current working directory 
`ls -d */` can be used. 
And If you need to list the hidden directories use this command 
`ls -d .*/`

Answer (score 5):

`find specifiedpath -type d`

If you don't want to recurse in subdirectories, you can do this instead:

`find specifiedpath -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`

Note that "dot" directories (whose name start with `.`) will be listed too; but not the special directories `.` nor `..`.  If you don't want "dot" directories, you can just `grep` them out:

`find specifiedpath -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | grep -v '^\.'`

Comment: Upvote for mentioning `mindepth` to get rid of `.`! 

Answer (score 5):

Long listing of directories

```
ls -l | grep  '^d'
```

Listing directories

```
ls -d */
```

Comment: Do you have any good reason to duplicate already existing answers?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `tree` command with its `d` switch to accomplish this.

```
% tree -d tstdir
tstdir
|-- d1
|   `-- d11
|       `-- d111
`-- d2
    `-- d21
        `-- d211

6 directories
```

see `man tree` for more info.

Comment: I didn't downvote, just had the same question. It appears your answer is a dupe of echox's, maybe that's why?.

Comment: @Louis - thanks I never even noticed his mention of `tree`. Oh well, wasn't my intent to steal anyone's thunder.

Comment: upvoting for the visualization of what tree does

Comment: I believe the downvotes are because it's a the same answer as  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667405/523742

Comment: @TiagoCardoso - mine predates that one by 2 years.

Comment: As I can see, yours: Dec 21 '12 / echox: Sep 8 '10... so he predates you... is that the case or I'm seeing it the other way round?

Comment: @TiagoCardoso - didn't even see that he mentions tree in his, only the `ls` bit. I'm leaving it, regardless, his doesn't show an example.

Comment: Yeah - I like your example and would suggest to delete yours - was just explaining _why_ some downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

**If I have this directory:**

`ls -l`

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nagios nagios     11 août   2 18:46 conf_nagios -> /etc/icinga
-rw-------  1 nagios nagios 724930 août  15 21:00 dead.letter
-rw-r--r--  1 nagios nagios  12312 août  23 00:13 icinga.log
-rw-r--r--  1 nagios nagios   8323 août  23 00:12 icinga.log.gz
drwxr-xr-x  2 nagios nagios   4096 août  23 16:36 tmp
```

**To get all directories, use -L to resolve links:**

`ls -lL | grep '^d'`

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 nagios nagios   4096 août  15 21:22 conf_nagios
drwxr-xr-x 2 nagios nagios   4096 août  23 16:41 tmp
```

**Without -L:**

`ls -l | grep '^d'`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 nagios nagios   4096 août  23 16:41 tmp
```

*conf_nagios* directory is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This has been working for me:

```
ls -F | grep /
```

(But, I am switching to `echo */` as mentioned by @nos)

Answer (score 2):

```
### If you need full path of dir and list selective dir with "name" of dir(or dir_prefix*):
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "SL*"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
ls -d */
```

Will list all directories

```
ls -ld */
```

will list all directories in long form

```
ls -ld */ .*/
```

will list all directories, including hidden directories, in long form.

---

I have recently switched to zsh (MacOS  Catalina), and found that:

```
ls -ld */ .*/
```

no longer works *if* the current directory contains no hidden directories.

```
zsh: no matches found: .*/
```

It will print the above error, but also will fail to print any directories.

```
ls -ld *(/) .*(/)
```

Also fails in the same way.

So far I have found that this:

```
ls -ld */;ls -ld .*/
```

is a decent workaround. The `;` is a command separator. But it means that if there are no hidden directories, it will list directories, and still print the error for no hidden directories:

```
foo
bar
zsh: no matches found: .*/
```

---

`ls` is the shell command for list contents of current directory
`-l` is the flag to specify that you want to list in Longford (one item per line + a bunch of other cool information)
`-d` is the flag to list all directories "as files" and not recursively
`*/` is the argument 'list all files ending in a slash'
`*` is a simple regex command for "anything", so `*/` is asking the shell to list "anything ending in '/'"

See `man ls` for more information.

---

I put this:

`alias lad="ls -ld */;ls -ld .*/"`

in my .zshrc, and it seems to work fine.

NOTE: I've also discovered that

`ls -ld .*/ 2> /dev/null`

doesn't work, as it still prints sterr to the terminal. I'll update my answer if/when I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that shows linked directories.
I slightly prefer it because it's a subset of the "normal" ls -l output:

```
ls -1d */ | rev | cut -c2- | rev | xargs ls -ld --color=always
```

Answer (score 1):

To list only directories in a specified path,just type

```
ls -l | grep drw
```

Comment: This might include files, if any filenames include `drw`, and would exclude any directories that are not owner-readable and -writeable. `grep ^d` works better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer most people will want.

```
ls -l | grep -E '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
```

The directory names, and nothing but the directory names.

Answer (score 1):

I find there are many good answers listed before me. But I would like to add a command which we already use it several time, and so very easy to list all the directories with less effort:

> `cd`

**(Note: After cd give a space) and press tab twice, it will list only all the directories in current working directory.** Hope this is easy to use. Please let me know if there is any problem with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a Bash script, I would typically try to do it in a way that does not execute any external program (grep, sed, ls, ...)

```
for i in * ; do 
  if [[ -d "$i" ]] ; then
    echo "$i" 
  fi
done
```

or as a single compact line

```
for i in * ; do [[ -d "$i" ]] && echo "$i" ; done
```

And if I need to reuse the list of directories, I would typically put it into an array:

```
DIRS=() ; for i in * ; do [[ -d "$i" ]] && DIRS+=("$i") ; done
```

and then use `"${DIRS[*]}"` or `"${DIRS[@]}"` to expand the array as in

```
for dir in "${DIRS[@]}" ; do 
   echo "Do something with directory $dir"
done
```

Another benefit of that approach is that it is very robust. It can handle spaces and newline in the directory names.

Answer (score 0):

`du -d1` is perhaps the shortest option. (As long as you don't need to pipe the input to another command.)