# Groovy get directory method does not return all the directories

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to get all the directories that are under one directory(deployment) by using groovy(in Jenkins pipeline). To do this I used the following code snippet.

```
def currentDir = new File("${WORKSPACE}/deployment")
currentDir.eachFile FileType.DIRECTORIES, {
  println it.name
}
```

After executing this I am only receiving one directory even though there are several directories.

I tried another code snipped which gave me the entire path of the directory. But still here also I am only getting one directory path even though there are several directories.

```
def dir = new File("${WORKSPACE}/deployment")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.DIRECTORIES) { directory ->
  println directory
}
```

What I actually want is the **1st solution** but with all the directories. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a setting on Jenkins pipeline to make sure that all the directories are getting visible? Please note I also allowed  `In Script Approval` in order to execute this.

Comment: Try to use the [findFiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) function from the Pipeline Utility Steps, it will make everything much more easy.

Comment: I actually want only the directories in a particular path. Is it possible to get only the directories from findFiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

- Groovy methods like `.each*`, `.find*` and similar ones that iterate over collections can be [problematic in pipeline code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37594635/7571258).
- The code will fail when trying to execute on a different node than "master". Groovy/Java code always runs on master, so it doesn't have direct access to `WORKSPACE` directory on another node. The code would try to find the directory on the master instead of the current node.

Unfortunately there is no built-in Jenkins function to iterate over directories (`findFiles` only iterates over files).

A good workaround is to use [shell code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3667329/7571258):

```
// Get directory names by calling shell command
def shOutput = sh( returnStdout: true, script: 'find * -maxdepth 0 -type d' )

// Split output lines into an array
def directories = shOutput.trim().split('\r?\n')

// Make sure to use "for" instead of ".each" to work around Jenkins bugs
for( name in directories ) {
    println name
}
```

By passing `returnStdout: true` to the [`sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) step it will return the standard output of the command. Use `trim()` to strip any extraneous line breaks from the end and `split()` to create an array from the output lines.

---

Here is the **PowerShell** version of that code (it's mostly the same except for the first line):

```
// Get directory names by calling shell command
def shOutput = powershell( returnStdout: true, script: '(Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name' )

// Split output lines into an array
def directories = shOutput.trim().split('\r?\n')

// Make sure to use "for" instead of ".each" to work around Jenkins bugs
for( name in directories ) {
    println name
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I used the shell version of the code snippet. Followed `ls -l | grep -E '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` as I only wanted the directory name.